# Removing html tags what is the difference between `*?` and `*`?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace all html tags from a string in JavaScript,

I would like to know what is the difference between

using `*?` or only `*`

Question: Is the `*?` in the expression is equivalent to `*`.

A)
  text.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '')

B)
    text.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*>/gm, '')

Comment: Do not sanitize HTML via regex.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/549471

Answer (score 0):

> Question: Is the `*?` in the expression is equivalent to `*`.

No. The latter is the greedy quantifier that matches as much characters as possible. cf. http://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html